Npm builds a wrong path to local user appdata folder
Example:
C:\Users\UserPC>npm install -g yarn
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\UserPC\"C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Roaming\npm"
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'C:\Users\UserPC\"C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Roaming\npm"'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

Windows 10.
Everything works fine for projects, all paths resolved correctly.
Tryed on fully reinstalled node.js
